# JS .click() not working when clicking button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 text boxs: **Height, Weight, BMI** and a Button called "**Calculate**" the JS function has to calculate the BMI of the person that clicks the button "**Calculate**", but it doesn't seem to work, I click the button and it does nothing, why is that? Do I have to create other class to put the JS code?

***This is the edited view and the JS function :***

```
   @model IEnumerable<FitnessWebApplication.Models.Measurement>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}



    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>

        @section scripts{
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#calculate').click(function () {
                    var weight = Number($('#Weight').val());
                    var height = Number($('#Height').val());
                    var bmi = height / (weight * weight);
                    $('#BMIBox').val(bmi);
                });
            });//jq
        }
    </script>

<h2>Your Measurements</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">


    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Weight)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Height)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Neck)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Waist)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Taken)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Weight) kg
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Height) cm
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Neck) cm
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Waist) cm
            </td>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Taken)
            </th>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>

<hr />

<h1>Calculate</h1>
<hr />
<h2>BMI</h2>

<form>



    <table>

        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Weight:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Weight" class="form-control" id="Weight" /></div><b>kg</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Height:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Height" class="form-control" id="Height" /></div><b>cm</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>BMI:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" name="BMI" class="form-control" id="BMIBox" /></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-default" id="calculate" />

        </div>

    </div>



</form>

<hr />
<h2>BF% (aproximated)</h2>
<p>(All the measurements must be taken at the narrowest point)</p>

<form>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Male</b></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Male" /></td>
            <td><b>Female</b></td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="Female" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Height:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Height" class="form-control" /></div><b>cm</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Waist:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Waist" class="form-control" /></div><b>cm</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Hip:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Hip" class="form-control" /></div><b>cm</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>Neck:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-5"><input type="text" name="Neck" class="form-control" /></div><b>cm</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right"><b>BF%:</b></td>
            <td align="left"><div class="col-xs-4"><input type="text" name="BF%" class="form-control" /></div><b>%</b></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='<%: @Url.Action("CalculateBF", "Measurements") %>'">
        </div>
    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Open your browser console and see whether you have any script errors.

Comment: Let's think about event handlers, like `$("#element").click()`. This says "Find anything with an ID of `element`, and attach a `click` event to it." Pretty simple, right? But what if you tried to do that *before `element` was even on the page*? That's what your code is doing. You're not waiting for `#calculate` to load before you try and attach things to it. The selector `$("#calculate")` won't find anything on the page. Try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` instead.

Comment: Already tried that, but is not working.

Comment: The `@section scripts{}` needs to `@RenderSection("scripts")` to adding it to a special point of your view and you must use it only when your view uses a `Layout`. In a simple (without layout) `.cshtml` file, you should use simple `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
         $('body').on("click", "#calculate" , function () {
              var weight = Number($('#Weight').val());
              var height = Number($('#Height').val());
              var bmi = height / (weight * weight);
              $('#BMIBox').val(bmi);
        });
     });
</script>
```

Important things:

- first `$(function(){})` is equals to `document.ready`.
- address of js file.  Your `src` must based on the `view` file. If the `jquery.js` is exactly beside final html, your src is correct. If the jquery file exists in root, you can try this: `src="/jquery.js"`
- If you want to check that your scripts is executed, add this line before binding click event:
     `alert("Reached here!");`
- priority of running scripts. jQuery must load before other scripts.
- press F12. Now in `console` tab, type this: `$("div")`

If you get correct answer,  jquery is loaded successfully.

- use `.on()` when your element may be added to page later (or exists now). Thus, in this sample it is not necessary.

Tip:

`.cshtml` files, compiles to simple html outputs. Only if you want to use `layouts`, `sections` are useful.

Scripts are a common part of html file, thus you can add them without any extra parts.

My above code will be correct, when you wrap all html tags in `<body></body>`

Comment: At last I was able to make it work, the problem was in the <script src="jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 1):

1. You are using asp.net-mvc
2. You have also using shared layout for, Folder : views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

Solution is in following steps

1. Make sure you have included jQuery on shared layout
2. You must apply `@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)` after including jquery in shared layout file
3. After that open second file where you want to apply click event
4. apply your jQuery only between below code:

```js
@section scripts{
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){    
                //Your code will be here
            });//jq
    </script>
}
```

Comment: By " your code will be here" you mean all this code?:  $('#calculate').click(function () {
        var weight = Number($('#Weight').val());
        var height = Number($('#Height').val());
        var bmi = height / (weight * weight);
        $('#BMIBox').val(bmi);
    });

Comment: Yes, also use your browser console to check any other.

Comment: Do the @section scripts{
     $(document).ready(function(){    
                //Your code will be here
            });//jq
    } has to be between <script> </script> tags, I have edited my code